# Multidimensional Array on TWIG loop

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I'm trying to save some values into a multiarray on Twig, but for some reason, it's not working.

I want to save in an array a list of users and some values of them. I am using merge function to create the multi array.

```
{% for result in results %}
        {% set users = users|merge({ ('name'~loop.index):result.name,('age'~loop.index):result.age,('credits'~loop.index):result.credits}) %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: What does "is not working" mean?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this out :

```
{% set users = [] %}
{% for result in results %}
    {% set users = users|merge([{ 'name' : result.name, 'age' : result.age, 'credits' : result.credits }]) %}
{% endfor %}
```